# Jersey + Weblogic - javax.net.ssl.SSLKeyException: FATAL Alert:BAD_CERTIFICATE

Tags: jersey, weblogic

I am sitting second whole day on a problem and giving up. I have written a jersey client which **works on Jetty**, and **doesnt work on Weblogic**. The reason is propably hidden in certificate: CN = "*.somecompany.com". Weblogic doesnt like wildcards in CN. Does anybody has working solution for that ?

I added these to Weblogic start params, but Weblogic uses many other clients, so **I dont want to add these parameter: ignoreHostnameVerification:** -

```
-Dssl.debug=true -Dweblogic.security.SSL.ignoreHostnameVerification=true 
-Dweblogic.security.SSL.enforceConstraints=off 
-Dweblogic.nodemanager.sslHostNameVerificationEnabled=false
-Dweblogic.security.SSL.allowSmallRSAExponent=true
-Dweblogic.security.SSL.ignoreHostnameVerification=true
```

I also accessed a REST service using webbrowser and downloaded certificate to disk an then added it to truststore using keytool.. It still doesnt work.

**The only and best way would be to write something custom that validate hostname?? Maybe this wildcard is a problem.. But I am newbie, no idea how to write it, a working example would be greatly appreciated, I won't be able to do it myself :**/

Below are exceptions that I found (not sure which were present and when but it is still not working) I was trying to fix it by:

1) Importing whole certificate chain to truststore (Java and Weblogic truststores)

2) Adding starting parameters to Weblogic, but it is not a good solution

```
com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientHandlerException: javax.net.ssl.SSLKeyException: FATAL 
Alert:BAD_CERTIFICATE - A corrupt or unuseable certificate was received.
com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientHandlerException: 
javax.net.ssl.SSLKeyException: FATAL Alert:BAD_CERTIFICATE - A corrupt 
or unuseable certificate was received.
         at 
    com.sun.jersey.client.urlconnection.URLConnectionClientHandler.handle(URLConnectionClientHa    ndler.java:131)
         at com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client.handle(Client.java:629)
     at 
com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource.handle(WebResource.java:601)
     at 
com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource.access$200(WebResource.java:74)
     at 
com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource$Builder.post(WebResource.java:507)
     at
```

SECOND

```
with Severity: FATAL, Type: 42
java.lang.Exception: New alert stack
    at com.certicom.tls.record.alert.Alert.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at         com.certicom.tls.record.handshake.HandshakeHandler.handleHandshakeMessages(Unknown Source)
    at com.certicom.tls.record.MessageInterpreter.interpretContent(Unknown Source)
    at com.certicom.tls.record.MessageInterpreter.decryptMessage(Unknown Source)
    at com.certicom.tls.record.ReadHandler.processRecord(Unknown Source)
    at com.certicom.tls.record.ReadHandler.readRecord(Unknown Source)
    at com.certicom.tls.record.ReadHandler.readUntilHandshakeComplete(Unknown Source)
    at com.certicom.tls.interfaceimpl.TLSConnectionImpl.completeHandshake(Unknown     Source)
    at com.certicom.tls.record.WriteHandler.write(Unknown Source)
    at com.certicom.io.OutputSSLIOStreamWrapper.write(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(BufferedOutputStream.java:82)
    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flush(BufferedOutputStream.java:140)
    at java.io.FilterOutputStream.flush(FilterOutputStream.java:140)
    at weblogic.net.http.HttpURLConnection.writeRequests(HttpURLConnection.java:154)
    at weblogic.net.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:358)
    at     weblogic.net.http.SOAPHttpsURLConnection.getInputStream(SOAPHttpsURLConnection.java:37)
    at weblogic.net.http.HttpURLConnection.getHeaderField(HttpURLConnection.java:702)
    at weblogic.net.http.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnection.java:962)
    at      com.sun.jersey.client.urlconnection.URLConnectionClientHandler._invoke(URLConnectionClientHandler.java:217)
    at     com.sun.jersey.client.urlconnection.URLConnectionClientHandler.handle(URLConnectionClientHandler.java:129)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client.handle(Client.java:629)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource.handle(WebResource.java:601)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource.access$200(WebResource.java:74)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource$Builder.post(WebResource.java:507)
    at
```

THIRD

```
 E7C0E2529308F> <> <1387573464164> <BEA-000000> <Failure loading trusted CA list
java.security.cert.CertificateParsingException: Could not set value for ASN.1     string     object.
    at com.certicom.security.cert.internal.x509.X509V3CertImpl.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.certicom.tls.interfaceimpl.CertificateSupport.addTrustedCertificate(Unknown      Source)
    at com.certicom.net.ssl.SSLContext.addTrustedCertificate(Unknown Source)
    at com.bea.sslplus.CerticomSSLContext.addTrustedCA(Unknown Source)
    at weblogic.security.utils.SSLContextWrapper.addTrustedCA(SSLContextWrapper.java:62)
    at weblogic.security.utils.SSLSetup.getSSLContext(SSLSetup.java:320)
    at weblogic.net.http.HttpsClient.openServer(HttpsClient.java:334)
    at weblogic.net.http.HttpsClient.New(HttpsClient.java:566)
    at weblogic.net.http.HttpsURLConnection.getHttpClient(HttpsURLConnection.java:339)
    at weblogic.net.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:408)
    at weblogic.net.http.SOAPHttpsURLConnection.getInputStream(SOAPHttpsURLConnection.java:37)
    at weblogic.net.http.HttpURLConnection.getHeaderField(HttpURLConnection.java:702)
    at weblogic.net.http.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnection.java:962)
    at com.sun.jersey.client.urlconnection.URLConnectionClientHandler._invoke(URLConnectionClientHandler.java:217)
    at com.sun.jersey.client.urlconnection.URLConnectionClientHandler.handle(URLConnectionClientHandler.java:129)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client.handle(Client.java:629)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource.handle(WebResource.java:601)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource.access$200(WebResource.java:74)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource$Builder.post(WebResource.java:507)
    at
```

Comment: It sounds like your trust store is bad. Are you setting `"-Dweblogic.security.SSL.trustedCAKeyStore` to something? Reference here: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11035_01/wls100/secmanage/identity_trust.html

Comment: No, I dont set it, should I? Correct me if I am wrong, but I think not. On a weblogic console I see that DemoTrust.jks is selected. Inside this jks are all known CA. I may have imported this last certificate in chain that has CN="*.somcompany.com" and I know that Weblogic doesnt support wildcards in certificates - meybe thats why this error occurs: ava.security.cert.CertificateParsingException: Could not set value for ASN.1. Besides webservices based on CXF and using other certificates - without wildcards works using ssl. 
Errors doesnt say that the certificate is not trusted but it is BAD

Comment: Try turning on Environment > Servers > [my server] > SSL > Advanced > Use JSSE SSL as per http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27928157/cannot-access-https-from-weblogic

Answer (score 0):

try to add the site certificate  to you weblogic truststore and then add the below param in your weblogic startup

```
-DUseSunHttpHandler=true
-Dssl.SocketFactory.provider=sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketFactoryImpl 
-Dssl.ServerSocketFactory.provider=sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketFactoryImpl
```

i have a problem like yours and by this post i solve it 
[Cannot access HTTPS from Weblogic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27928157/cannot-access-https-from-weblogic)

Answer (score 0):

Issue fixed by adding these entry in JVM arguments

```
"-Dweblogic.security.SSL.nojce=true"
"-Dweblogic.ssl.JSSEEnabled=true"
"-Dweblogic.security.SSL.enableJSSE=true"
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.