# javax.net.ssl.SSLKeyException: FATAL Alert:BAD_CERTIFICATE - A corrupt or unuseable certificate was received

Tags: java, web-services, jakarta-ee, wsdl2java

I am getting this below error when trying to access an WSDL endpoint.

First I have created the client jar using cliengen ant task and then created a simple java class to test the wsdl end point and I am getting below error-

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLKeyException: FATAL Alert:BAD_CERTIFICATE - A corrupt or unuseable certificate was received.
    at com.certicom.tls.interfaceimpl.TLSConnectionImpl.fireException(Unknown Source)
    at com.certicom.tls.interfaceimpl.TLSConnectionImpl.fireAlertSent(Unknown Source)
    at com.certicom.tls.record.handshake.HandshakeHandler.fireAlert(Unknown Source)
    at com.certicom.tls.record.handshake.HandshakeHandler.handleHandshakeMessages(Unknown Source)
    at com.certicom.tls.record.MessageInterpreter.interpretContent(Unknown Source)
    at com.certicom.tls.record.MessageInterpreter.decryptMessage(Unknown Source)
    at com.certicom.tls.record.ReadHandler.processRecord(Unknown Source)
    at com.certicom.tls.record.ReadHandler.readRecord(Unknown Source)
    at com.certicom.tls.record.ReadHandler.readUntilHandshakeComplete(Unknown Source)
    at com.certicom.tls.interfaceimpl.TLSConnectionImpl.completeHandshake(Unknown Source)
    at com.certicom.tls.record.WriteHandler.write(Unknown Source)
    at com.certicom.io.OutputSSLIOStreamWrapper.write(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(BufferedOutputStream.java:66)
    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.write(BufferedOutputStream.java:105)
    at java.io.FilterOutputStream.write(FilterOutputStream.java:80)
    at weblogic.webservice.binding.soap.HttpClientBinding.writeToStream(HttpClientBinding.java:430)
    at weblogic.webservice.binding.soap.HttpClientBinding.send(HttpClientBinding.java:219)
    at weblogic.webservice.core.handler.ClientHandler.handleRequest(ClientHandler.java:37)
    at weblogic.webservice.core.HandlerChainImpl.handleRequest(HandlerChainImpl.java:143)
    at weblogic.webservice.core.ClientDispatcher.send(ClientDispatcher.java:231)
    at weblogic.webservice.core.ClientDispatcher.dispatch(ClientDispatcher.java:143)
    at weblogic.webservice.core.DefaultOperation.invoke(DefaultOperation.java:471)
    at weblogic.webservice.core.DefaultOperation.invoke(DefaultOperation.java:457)
    at weblogic.webservice.core.rpc.StubImpl._invoke(StubImpl.java:303)
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: Is this two way SSL or one way?

Comment: Try adding: -Djavax.net.debug=ssl to your java args, and see if that produces more pertinent logs.

Comment: No.. It is not generating more logs..I am trying to access http wsdl end points. I can not understand why it is throwing SSLKeyException.

Comment: is that I need to have server certificate? If yes then how can I get this?

Comment: Try turning on Environment > Servers > [my server] > SSL > Advanced > Use JSSE SSL as per http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27928157/cannot-access-https-from-weblogic

Answer (score 3):

I was able to get resolve the exception by updating \Oracle\Middleware\user_projects\domains\my_domain\bin\setDomainEnv.cmd with below commands

```
set JAVA_OPTIONS=%JAVA_OPTIONS% -DUseSunHttpHandler=true -Dssl.SocketFactory.provider=sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketFactoryImpl -Dssl.ServerSocketFactory.provider=sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketFactoryImpl
```

Answer (score 1):

Fixed this issue by adding following lines in JVM arguments.

```
-Dweblogic.security.SSL.nojce=true 
-Dweblogic.ssl.JSSEEnabled=true 
-Dweblogic.security.SSL.enableJSSE=true
```

Don't forget to recycle JVM. :)

Answer (score 0):

I was getting a similar when trying to upload a file to an S3 Bucket on AWS from a WebLogic application.  I added the following lines

```
JAVA_OPTIONS="${JAVA_OPTIONS} -DUseSunHttpHandler=true -Dssl.SocketFactory.provider=sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketFactoryImpl -Dssl.ServerSocketFactory.provider=sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketFactoryImpl" 

just before this command

JAVA_OPTIONS="${JAVA_OPTIONS}"
export JAVA_OPTIONS
```

in

```
\Oracle\Middleware\user_projects\domains\my_domain\bin\setDomainEnv.cmd
```

and my issue was resolved.  Just make sure to restart WebLogic after the amendment.

Answer (score -1):

Add this in startup params

```
-DUseSunHttpHandler=true 
-Dssl.SocketFactory.provider=sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketFactoryImpl 
-Dssl.ServerSocketFactory.provider=sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketFactoryImpl
```